# Call Javascript function from a URL

Tags: javascript, url

Is it possible to call a javascript function from the URL? I am basically trying to leverage JS methods in a page I don't have access to the source.

Something like: `http://www.example.com/mypage.aspx?javascript:printHelloWorld()`

I suspect the answer to this is no but, just wondered if there was a way to do it.

Comment: What behaviour would your URL have to display - do you want to execute Javascript in the context of that site?

Comment: The `http:` at the start of the URI tells the browser "I want you to make an HTTP request", so HTTP request it does. There is no way around it, I think.

Comment: If I paste `javascript:alert("Hi");` into my Firefox (28.0) address bar and press Enter, nothing happens. Maybe this has been disabled? ... Yes, apparently it has been disabled because idiots could be convinced to paste anything into their address bar. Found the info here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18782801/111036

Comment: copy paste doesn't work, but if you type it, it works, looks like it not disabled, but parsed when pasted.

Comment: Note: it only works in Firefox when 1. you're on an actual (not empty) page and 2. you explicitly put "javascript:" before it.

Comment: Good question though. :)  I would assume though that reacts as a param and invalid character call since URL http get action considers anything following '?' a parameter. Also, this would be a client side security threat.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

There isn't from a hyperlink, no.  Not unless the page has script inside specifically for this and it's checking for some parameter....but for your question, no, there's no built-in support in browsers for this.

There are however [bookmarklets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet) you can bookmark to quickly run JavaScript functions from your address bar; not sure if that meets your needs, but it's as close as it gets.

Comment: I am basically trying to leveradge JS methods in a page I dont have access to the source.

Answer (score 49):

You can use Data URIs.
For example:
`data:text/html,<script>alert('hi');</script>`

For more information visit: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs

Comment: i always thought data url is only for images, thanks this is really amazing :)

Comment: you can't append this to a url.

Comment: Some browsers may block this with a message: ```Navigation to toplevel data: URI not allowed (Blocked loading of: “data:text/html,<script>alert('hi');</script>”)```

Comment: It works on **Google Chrome** Version 80.0.3987.132 (Official Build) (64-bit).

Comment: it works in `Chrome 80.0.3987.162 (Official Build) (64-bit)` and in `Firefox 72.0.2 (64 bit)`

Comment: Before you get too excited - **this will not execute on the current page**. It will load a blank document and run JS in that context.

Answer (score 45):

Write in address bar

```
javascript:alert("hi");
```

Make sure you write in the beginning: javascript:

Comment: It doesn't work on **Google Chrome** Version 80.0.3987.132 (Official Build) (64-bit). Chrome automatically strips the `javascript:` prefix from the address bar.

Comment: @stomy You need to type `javascript:` manually, unfortunately

Comment: @wjandrea You can, however, create a bookmark (you still have to manually type the prefix) and it will execute the Javascript when you click on it. I've made some pretty neat stuff this way; I believe I heard from somewhere that these are called Bookmarklets.

Comment: Is it possible that this doesn't work anymore?

Comment: it works, be sure to type javascript:

Answer (score 8):

/test.html#alert('heello')

```
test.html
<button onClick="eval(document.location.hash.substring(1))">do it</button>
```

Comment: Note that this evaluating user input is very dangerous practice and should usually not be allowed.

Comment: Yes, this is quite insane. There are workplaces where you would get fired because of this type of insanity.

Comment: This leads to reflected cross-site scripting (XSS) issues as pointed out by @domenukk.

Answer (score 7):

**About the [`window.location.hash`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_hash.asp) property:**
Return the anchor part of a URL.

---

**Example 1:**

```
//Assume that the current URL is 

var URL = "http://www.example.com/test.htm#part2";

var x = window.location.hash;

//The result of x will be:

x = "#part2"
```

**Exmaple 2:**

```
$(function(){   
    setTimeout(function(){
        var id = document.location.hash;
        $(id).click().blur();
    }, 200);
})
```

**Example 3:**

```
var hash = "#search" || window.location.hash;
window.location.hash = hash; 

switch(hash){   
case "#search":  
    selectPanel("pnlSearch");
    break;    
case "#advsearch":    

case "#admin":  

}
```

Answer (score 6):

you may also place the followinng

```
<a href='javascript:alert("hello world!");'>Click me</a>
```

to your html-code, and when you click on 'Click me' hyperlink, javascript will appear in url-bar and Alert dialog will show

Comment: *javascript will appear in url-bar* in what browser? I have never seen that. (I know javascript: links work, I'm just talking about the URL bar)

Comment: Neither have I.  I know you can type JS into the address bar

Comment: This is what I was looking for, whats this called?

Answer (score 3):

Using Eddy's answer worked very well as I had kind of the same problem.
Just call your url with the parameters : "www.mypage.html#myAnchor"

Then, in mypage.html :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var hash = window.location.hash;
  if(hash.length > 0){
    // your action with the hash
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use:

```js
(function() {
  var a = document.createElement("script");
  a.type = "text/javascript";
  a.src = "http://www.example.com/helloworld.js?" + Math.random();
  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(a)
})();
```

This basically creates a new JavaScript line in the head of the HTML to load the JavaScript URL you wish on the page itself.  This seems more like what you were asking for.  You can also change the `a.src` to the actual code, but for longer functions and stuff it becomes a problem.  The source link can also link to a JavaScript file on your computer if targeted that way.

Answer (score 2):

you can use like this situation: 
for example, you have a page:  `http://www.example.com/page.php`
then in that page.php, insert this code:

```
if (!empty($_GET['doaction']) && $_GET['doaction'] == blabla ){
echo '<script>alert("hello");</script>';
}
```

then, whenever you visit this url: `http://www.example.com/page.php?doaction=blabla`

then the alert will be automatically called.

Answer (score 1):

No; because it would make links extremely dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

you can execute javascript from url via events
Ex: `www.something.com/home/save?id=12<body onload="alert(1)"></body>`

does work if params in url are there.

Comment: It looks like you have tested with an unsecure site which is prone to XSS attack.

Comment: lol i hope this is not your own site because if this works then that site is very insecure.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Chrome extension called [Bookmarklet URL](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bookmarklet-url/lnldegfbcpbaloalllolfjbekjkjieom?hl=en) (no affiliation).  To append a URL with JavaScript, so that the JavaScript command is executed just after loading the webpage, one can use `?bmlet=javascript:`

**Example: Display an alert box**

```
https://github.com/?bmlet=javascript:alert("Hi");
```

**Example: Enable spell-checking while editing a GitHub README file**
[Obviously, a spelling checking extension must be originally available.]

```
https://github.com/<username>/<repositoryname>/edit/main/README.md?bmlet=javascript:document.getElementById("code-editor").setAttribute("spellcheck","true");
```

On some pages, it might take some time, as the JavaScript command runs after completely loading the page. Simple commands like `alert("Hi");` should run quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I am a student and I have just realized my school blocked JavaScript from the address bar. It works with the "a" tag on a .html file but not on the bar anymore. I am not asking for help, I would just like to share this.

Answer (score -1):

You can do one thing that is you can first open the link [www.example.com](http://www.example.com). Then you can search:
javascript:window.alert("Hello World!")

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: That's like saying "You can open www.example.com and then click on the button that runs the js". It's not what OP wants