# Is there an alternative to `javascript:` for running JS from the URL bar?

Tags: javascript, chromium

I am wanting to run JS that is put into the URL bar.

I have tried putting `javascript: // js code here.` in the URL bar but this does not seem to be supported / do anything in my Chromium based browser. So, I am looking for an alternative to this.

I am wanting a offline based solution (eg, I am not wanting to run JS from a website).

Comment: `javascript:` still works for me, so I guess bookmarklets are still supported

Comment: *"I am wanting a offline based solution (eg, I am not wanting to run JS from a website)."* In that case, I wouldn't use a browser at all. Instead, use [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/), which provides a non-browser JavaScript environment. You might combine it with a decent IDE like VS Code or Webstorm so you can edit your code in a rich environment, then run it via a keypress that automatically runs it in Node.js and connects to its debugging API.

Answer (score -1):

My alternative was: `data: // js code here`.

found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39376992/20969105

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) If that answer **answered** your question, don't repost the answer. Instead, close your question as a duplicate of that question. (That's if, as I assume is the case, you found that answer in the ~13 minutes between posting the question and the answer above. If you posted the question *after* finding the answer, just don't post the question at all.)