# Is there a way to link directly to specific content on this JS/CSS page?

Tags: css, jscript

I would like to link to a specific photo gallery on a JS/CSS page.

If you go to witold.org -> "SHOW ALL PHOTO SERIES" -> "Indian Road Signs"  a gallery of photos will load up.

Is there a way to link directly to this gallery so as to avoid the clicking through from the main page?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ways to insert javascript into URL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/705533/ways-to-insert-javascript-into-url)

Answer (score 0):

No.

What you are requesting is a massive security violation. You are basically trying to set the current state of the page by calling this function: `changeContent('series',10,'inrroadsigns');` from the url.

Duplicate question: [Ways to insert javascript into URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/705533/1026459)

Comment: Thanks for the other link.  I was keeping my fingers crossed that there might be some work around...